# Variables not showing content on Jade template

Tags: node.js, pug

I am learning Node.js using a book. There was an example that as a learning experience I converted from what it was to a SQL version of it.

This single page is only intended to display user information. I load the user information on a middleware then pass it to the Jade template. Everything working up to this point.

When I want to render the template below, wherever I user content from the user object, it renders nothing.

```
h1= user.Name
h2 Bio
p= user.Bio
form(action="/users/" + encodeURIComponent(user.User), method="POST")
  input(name="_method", type="hidden", value="DELETE")
  input(type="submit", value="Delete")
```

To check if the object was without content, I added this 2 lines on the front

```
-console.log ( 'Inside Jade' )
-console.log ( user )
```

and the result in the console is:

```
Inside Jade
[ { Name: 'Jennifer Lopes',
    User: 'jenny',
    Password: 'asd',
    Bio: 'Actress and singer' } ]
```

So this tells me that the information is there, but is not being rendered.

The code used to render the template is:

```
app.get ('/users/:name', loadUser, function ( req, res, next ) {
res.render ( 'users/profile', { title: 'User profile', user: req.user });
});
```

Can you please help me to understand what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to render the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hard to tell without seeing all your code, but per the output of your console it looks like user is actually an array of objects based upon the brackets, if you change your jade template to output something like user[0].Name does it give you your expected values?

Comment: User is the result of a node-mysql connection.query. I got the user name, I do a query on the MySql database for a user with that name and display the results if the user is found (the logic if the user is not found is not written yet). If I add the [0] as you mentioned, it does display the template as expected. Although I can live with that, what is the right way to write it so I dont need the index as if it were an array?

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with node-mysql, but looking at the docs it appears it will always return an array or put another way it doesn't have a built in helper method to return a single item when only one record is expected to return.  So that being said, I would change your controller line to be user: req.user[0] so your Jade logic doesn't have to worry about the array.  You could also do the same thing further upstream wherever your mysql query is occurring.

Comment: You could also at the beginning of your jade template create a variable in jade that contains the [0] item in your passed in data and use that variable in place of the array being passed in.  It would work but I would go with my previous suggestion of handling it in the controller.  I hope that helps and makes sense.